# What if it's just a dot without the name in the parentheses? e.g.: ORA-00001: unique constraint (.) violated. How to resolve this?

Tags: oracle

How can I resolve the unique constraint? What if it's just a dot without the name in the parentheses? e.g.:

```
ORA-00001: unique constraint (.) violated
```

Comment: Because you can't have a dot in a name or otherwise.

Comment: What are you actually asking here?

Comment: Have you actually seen this? `ORA-00001: unique constraint (.) violated`? What is your database version? How are you accessing the database - directly (SQL\*Plus), through a GUI like Toad or SQL Developer, through some application, ...? If it's not directly on the database, what happens if you try the same thing directly in SQL\*Plus? What is the owner name - and do you know the constraint name?

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include a [MRE] with: the `CREATE TABLE` statement(s) for the table(s) relating to the DML statement that generated the error; any `ALTER TABLE` statements required to create the constraints; and the DML statement that generated the error.

Answer (score 1):

You can get this error with some shenanigans:

1. Create a user with the name `"​"` *(Note: this is not an empty string, there is a single zero-width space (U+200B) character between the double-quotes.)*
2. Create a table with the constraint and give the constraint a similar zero-width space name:

   ```sql
   CREATE TABLE table_name (
     value INTEGER
           CONSTRAINT "​" UNIQUE
   );
   ```
3. Then if you:

   ```sql
   INSERT INTO table_name (value) VALUES (1);
   INSERT INTO table_name (value) VALUES (1);
   ```

   You will get the error:

   ```
   ORA-00001: unique constraint (​.​) violated
   ```

There is a table name and constraint name there but it is not visible as they are both zero-width characters.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=77d21570a31f1e18233681666c2d09ff) (just showing the constraint name since you can't create users in the fiddle)*

---

> How can I resolve the unique constraint?

In this case, the simplest method of resolving it is to not use unreadable names for users and/or constraints.

Other than that, copy-paste the error message into an application where you can view the hexadecimal/Unicode values of the characters in the string and work out that there are table and constraint names there that are not visible and then work from that in the normal method.